# Value of type '(UIDatePicker) -> ()' has no member 'date' In swift 5

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

Im trying to capture date to a variablew outside of funciton but I keep getting this message :

> Value of type '(UIDatePicker) -> ()' has no member 'date'

This is the code

```
var selectedDate: String?

@IBAction func datePicker(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    selectedDate = self.datePicker.date
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the function itself which makes no sense unless there is also an outlet `datePicker`.

Use the `sender` parameter

```
@IBAction func datePicker(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    selectedDate = sender.date
}
```

and declare `selectedDate` as `Date`

```
var selectedDate: Date?
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Im getting "Cannot assign value of type 'Date' to type 'String'" now.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you but what I need it tu put it a variable that changes when the datePicker change the state. Right now I have dateDisplay.text =  "\(selectedDate)" but it give me nil.

Comment: A backslash is missing: `dateDisplay.text = "\(selectedDate)"` but consider that you get a generic date string